# Call function after the function above has completed

Tags: jquery

Can anyone assist me in getting a function to be called, in this example the second() after the function before has finished? The first function called contains an ajax call.

```
function requestPost(postID, clientId) {

    first("path", { postID: postID, clientId: clientId});
    second(); // this is where I want to call the second() but only the first() has completed.

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Pass in the second function to the ajax call as the callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably specify the ajax function/library/whatever that's being used.  That'll simplify answers.  If that ajax function has a callback mechanism, you can just do:

```
var second = function second(){ // do stuff };
$.ajax({callback:second});
```

In other words, pass the function as a callback to the ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the jquery queue function
http://api.jquery.com/queue/